# Select rows having same Rate column value

Tags: oracle

In the following table I want Supp_ID that have same rate for same combination of Product and RouteCode

So, I should get all the rows except the first row.

```
Supp_ID    Product  RouteCode  Rate
25sdf-1    PROD1    2-00       0.0436
302qq-6    PROD1    1-00       0.0815
30wqa-6    PROD1    1-00       0.0815 
20xdf-1    PROD1    3-00       0.0936
28xdf-1    PROD1    3-00       0.0936
```

Comment: Just to clarify.. you want only records that share a rate with at least one other record?

Comment: i want Supp_ID that have same rate for same combination of Product and RouteCode.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Window function to help out here:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT supp_id, product, routecode, rate, 
             count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rate, Supp_Id, Product) as count_of_shared_rate 
      FROM table) t1
WHERE count_of_shared_rate > 1
```

Comment: I have tried similar thing earlier but not getting the proper result

Comment: @SachinVaidya - "not getting the proper result" in what way?

Comment: @mathguy - getting incorrect result.. I am not getting various suppliers with same rates across same product and route values, which is desired. Also, in the suggested solution, not sure why partition by contains only product and not route as well.

Comment: @SachinVaidya - I am just guessing here at information that is *not* present in your original formulation. Is the following true: for each SUPP_ID you may have many combinations of product and routeCode. You want to return only those different SUPP_ID that have the same rate for ALL possible combinations of product and routeCode, not just for ONE such combination. In the original problem it makes no difference, because each SUPP_ID had only ONE combination of product and routeCode. ...

Comment: @SachinVaidya  ..... Then: if you need for ALL combinations - do you ALSO need that they have **the same** combinations, before you even start comparing the rates? Or only for those combinations they BOTH have present in the table?

Comment: @mathguy I want - different SUPP_ID that have the same rate for ALL possible combinations of product and routeCode

Comment: @mathguy sorry for my previous comment, what I want is, different supp_id for same combination of prod and route with same rates

Comment: if we add routecode also in the partition then it works !!